# yql mess up with retrieved content

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp, yql

I'm trying to get raw content of my gist so that I could display.

Here is the code:

```
function requestCrossDomain(url, cb) {

    yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +
          "q=" + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + url + '" ') +
          "&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(yql, function (data) {
        if(data.results[0]){
            console.log(data.results[0]);
        }
    });
}

requestCrossDomain("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gongzhitaao/11357604/raw/7946d46c975337084b18ff1d59530acc59c9e010/index.html");
```

The `data.results[0]` does contain something, but it's garbage.  The code between `<script></script>` are separated by a `<p>` (in the `render` function) ??? Why?  Where am I wrong?

**Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gongzhitaao/3j3py/)**, as you can see, only part of the code between `<script>` is shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem.  It appears to be the parameter `compat="html5"`.  The default html spec is html4.  And also I need the `xpath` parameter to select the `<header>` content as well as the `<body>` content.  Hope the following code could be of some help to others:

```
function requestCrossDomain(url, cb) {

    yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +
        "q=" +
        encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + url + '" ') +
        encodeURIComponent('and compat="html5" and xpath="//html/head|//html/body"') +
        "&format=xml&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(yql, function (data) {
        if(data.results)
            cb(data.results);
    });
}
```